# What is the syntax for passing an array into a view, in the Play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework

When passing non string arguments, I tag the view with the following first line:

```
@(name: String,country: String)
```

to signal the framework that two arguments should be passed into it.

How do I signal that I'm waiting for a String[] argument?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In scala, this is written `Array[String]`, not `String[]`

Answer (score 7):

```
@(name: Array[String])
```

this should work, in Play you use scala template system